# Unable to add a windows group as SQL Server Login

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to add a windows group as a SQL Server login through TSQL but keep getting the below error.

**TSQL**

```
use master;
CREATE LOGIN [go.domain1.com\APPS-AllUsers] FROM WINDOWS;  
GO
```

**Error**

```
Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Windows NT user or group 'go.domain1.com\APPS-AllUsers' not found. Check the name again.
```

This group supposed to be part of Active Directory.

However I'm able to add another AD user using the same syntax as in

```
use master;
CREATE LOGIN [domain2\myuserid] FROM WINDOWS;  
GO
```

My queries are:-

1. Is the TSQL syntax to add Windows/AD user and group, same for both cases. **As per what I can reference from sources, it is.**
2. Is it possible the group actually doesn't exist in AD in that particular domain ?
3. Am I missing anything else?

BTW, the version of SQL SERVER (PDW on APS appliance) that I'm using is

```
Microsoft Parallel Data Warehouse - 10.0.8493.0 (X64) Nov 2 2016 22:01:10 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Parallel Data Warehouse (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

Thanks in advance for the pointers!

Attaching security group information.
[image]

Attaching output from PS get-adgroup command
[image]

Comment: Yes, groups are supported this way (at least on SQL Server proper; I don't think PDW differs in this regard, though). Is the name of the domain actually `abc.domain1.com` or rather `abc.domain1` or `abc` or something else local? T-SQL supports only the old style syntax for account names (`domain\account`) rather than the new style (`account@domain`), and the old style can get squirrely with qualified domain names.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, yes I suspect this as well. The team tells me that AD domain of the group is of the format that I mentioned i. e. abc.domain.com. Through the conventional syntax I&#39;m able to add a domain user as I mentioned (though that one is a different domain). And I&#39;m stuck with using TSQL only. Not sure what is the issue here. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Is your AD group marked as a security group or a distribution group? You can use `get-adgroup` in powershell to take a look. It needs to be a security group for this to work.

Comment: @BenThul  Thanks for the tip! Yes I noticed that as well in identity manager but the team told me that it's part of AD anyway. I asked them to change it to security group and then I will try again. Will keep you posted. Thanks again.

Comment: @BenThul I managed to get the team correct this and change this to security groups instead. I'm still facing the same issue i.e. `Windows NT user or group 'go.domain1.com\APPS-AllUsers' not found. Check the name again.` I tried all possible combinations of the domain qualifier such as `go.domain1.com\APPS-AllUsers`, `go\APPS-AllUsers`, `domain1.com\APPS-AllUsers`, no luck yet. Also attaching a screenshot for attributes of the group from Identity Manager, for reference.

Comment: Hmm - that screenshot is not showing me what I would like. What I'd like to see is the output of the following powershell command: `get-adgroup APPS-AllUsers| select groupcategory, groupscope`

Comment: @BenThul added screenshot for PS command. From the looks of it, seems the group in question can't be found. Would you say this group is not created properly in the first place (actually now recreated as security group). What could be missing here which is contributing it to be not visible, though it is showing up as a security group as per my earlier screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out few days back, through multiple tries using SSMS (to cross check, even though in this case TSQL was the only options available to me).

It turned out that the AD security groups have a few attribute for name one of them being **"Pre 200 name"** and this attribute is exactly how sql server identified these AD groups.

I tried this attribute with TSQL for adding groups names (rather than the actual group name) and it worked like a charm. Apparently, SSMS also uses this attribute behind the scenes.